# Determine image size to reduce image size Android

Tags: android, image-processing, compression

Is there away to reduce the image (taken from phone camera) storage capacity. As far as I know the parameters that can be changed are the quality, encoding and dimension of the image. For this I am using zetbaitsu/Compressor lib.

The question is how to determine required dimensions for cloud storage, so that the image has good quality on various android screen sizes/resolutions while significantly reducing storage requirements.

```
File image = fileMessageContainer.getFile();
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
int width = bmOptions.outWidth;
int height = bmOptions.outHeight;
Log.d("myApp", "uncompressed" +  width + " height: " +  height);

Bitmap bitmap = compressImages(image, width, height);
Log.d("myApp", "compressed" +  bitmap.getWidth() + " height: " +  
bitmap.getHeight());

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

Log.d("myApp", "original data " + byteArray.length);
```

---

```
    private Bitmap compressImages(File actualImage, int width, int height){
        try {
         return new Compressor(context)
        .setQuality(75)
        .setMaxHeight(height)
        .setMaxWidth(width)
        .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
        .compressToBitmap(actualImage);
        }catch (Exception e){
           Log.d("myApp", "compressImages-Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private byte[] convertToByteArray(Bitmap b){
        int bytes = b.getByteCount();

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
        b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

        return buffer.array(); //Get the underlying array containing the data.
    }
```

Console output

uncompressed width: 2448 height: 3264
compressed width: 2448 height: 3264
original data 31961088

Comment: you don't resize the image in your code. You just compress it as JPEG with 75% quality

Comment: yes, the question is how to determine resize dimensions while keeping aspect ratios, so that I dont have to assign random values.

Comment: that depends on how exactly you are going to use that image.

Comment: I am planing to display this image 3/4 size of the any screen. For convenience lets say full-screen size of different devices and should have good quality.

Comment: then what I'd suggest is to downscale it to FullHD (1080x1920), or similar to keep aspect ratio. It will look good on either 720x1280 or 1440x2560 screens. As an algorithm I'd suggest using this: decide which side (w or h) you are going to stick to. Let's say w (width). The target width will be 1080. Now to calculate target height, use formula: `targetHeight = targetWidth / actualWidth * actualHeight`. Now you have target dimensions and can resize your image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare aspect ratio then use it for your new width and height

```
float aspectRatio = bmOptions.outWidth/bmOptions.outHeight;

int width = 480; //Your choice
int height = Math.round(width / aspectRatio);

Bitmap bitmap = compressImages(image, width, height);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how to determine 480, while retaining quality but reducing storage requirements.